# MySQL database query from Java fails

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have this table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE CanteenMan.Foods (
 id TINYINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 type ENUM("soup","main","desert") DEFAULT "soup",
 name VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
 price FLOAT NULL DEFAULT NULL
)ENGINE = INNODB;
```

So if i want to insert new food, I should do this:

```
INSERT INTO Foods(id,type,name,price)
VALUES(NULL,"soup","somename",3.3);
```

And here is my problem now...I am using JDBC to add new foods in the table:

```
public void addFood(Meal f) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

     Class.forName (dbid.driver);
     Connection c = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dbid.url,dbid.user,dbid.pass);
     PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO foods(id,type,name,price"
            + "VALUES(NULL,?,?,?)");
     ps.setString(1,f.getType()); // here throws SQLException
     ps.setString(2, f.getName());
     ps.setFloat(3,f.getPrice());

     int rowsInserted = ps.executeUpdate();

     System.out.println("Rows inserted:"+rowsInserted);
 }
```

But this throws SQL Exception because MySQL wants here

```
+ "VALUES(NULL,?,?,?)");
```

to surround the values with "".Is it any way to make this query to be accepted from the  MySQL server ?

Comment: We need to see your `Meal` class, especially what the return value of `getType()` is.

Comment: @chrylis, I think the OP is wrong about the line where the error is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `sql` statement is missing a closing right parenthesis for the list of columns.

```
PreparedStatement ps = 
(PreparedStatement) c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO foods(id,type,name,price) "
                + "VALUES(NULL,?,?,?)");
```

Notice that after the price column is listed, I have inserted `)`.

Answer (score 0):

You Can write query like this:

public void addFood(Meal f) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

```
 Class.forName (dbid.driver);
 Connection c = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(dbid.url,dbid.user,dbid.pass);
 PreparedStatement ps = (PreparedStatement) c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO foods(id,type,name,price)
        VALUES(NULL,?,?,?)");
 ps.setString(1,f.getType()); // here throws SQLException
 ps.setString(2, f.getName());
 ps.setFloat(3,f.getPrice());

 int rowsInserted = ps.executeUpdate();

 System.out.println("Rows inserted:"+rowsInserted);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`foods` table `id` is uniqueid and primary key , so it should be like,

`PreparedStatement ps = 
(PreparedStatement) c.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO foods(type,name,price) "
                + "VALUES(?,?,?)");`